# Single MySQL query to fetch folder names, email count per folder

Tags: mysql

I have the following two MySQL tables for emails...

**mail_emails**

*Columns:* id, folder, user

**mail_folders**

*Columns:* id, name, user

I want to use only a single MySQL query to fetch the folder names and the number of emails per folder. Presuming the user id is 1, what would be the most efficient approach to this goal?

Comment: Is `mail_emails.folder` an integer representing a reference to `mail_folders.id` or is it a reference to `mail_folders.name`? Best to show the output of `desc mail_emails` and `desc mail_folders`

Comment: Yes, integers whenever possible, always for ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure of your database structure. But this should give you an idea.

```
SELECT *, count(e.folder) totalMail FROM mail_folders f INNER JOIN mail_emails e on e.folder = f.name  WHERE f.user = '1' GROUP BY e.folder
```

I am assuming that the `name` field in the `mail_folders` table is the same value that will be stored in `folder` field of `mail_emails` table.

Comment: You omitted `AS` for the alias? I'm testing this now...

Comment: @John, It is not compulsory.

Comment: MySQL is reporting a problem with `count(e.*)` part of the email, what could be the problem?

Comment: @John, I tested and update my query.

Comment: Edit the `f.name` just before `WHERE` to `f.id` and it works. Thanks!